# Help with 2 loops and an update in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I am working on a stored procedure that will trigger once a week so I am not worried about speed as much as getting the thing to work.

What I am trying to do is loop through a table called `households` that stores information about the houses, then using the `houseid` looping through a table called `individuals` which will returns more than one person therefore leading me to loop through that result to gather information.

My main goal is to concatenate all the names of the people in the household, and their codes

```
declare @RowNum int,
    @houseId nchar(10), 
    @hid nchar(25) 

    select @houseId=MAX(ID) FROM households     --start with the highest ID 
    Select @RowNum = Count(*) From households      --get total number of records
    WHILE @RowNum > 0                          --loop until no more records BEGIN       

    select @hid = id from households where ID = @houseid    --get other info from that row  

    DECLARE @RowCount INT

    SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM (select id, firstname,lastname,party_code from indviduals where householdid = @houseid) as table1)  
    DECLARE @code1 VARCHAR(50), @names1 VARCHAR(500), @lastname1 VARCHAR(50) 
    -- Declare an iterator
    DECLARE @I INT
    -- Initialize the iterator
    SET @I = (select min(id) from indviduals where householdid = @houseid)

    -- Loop through the rows of a table @myTable
    WHILE (@I <= @RowCount)
    BEGIN
            -- Declare variables to hold the data which we get after looping each record 
            DECLARE @code VARCHAR(50), @names VARCHAR(500), @lastname VARCHAR(50)    

            -- Get the data from table and set to variables
            SELECT @code = party_code, @names = firstname, @lastname = lastname FROM (select id, firstname,lastname,party_code from indviduals where householdid = @houseid) as table1  WHERE ID = @I
            -- Display the looped data



    set @code1 = (@code + ',' + @code1)
    set @names1 = (@names + ',' + @names1)
    set @lastname1 = @lastname
            -- Increment the iterator
            SET @I = @I  + 1
    END

    update households    
    SET firstnames=@names1, lastname=@lastname1, party_codes=@code1,
    where id = @houseid  

    select top 1 @houseId=ID 
    from households
    where ID < @houseID 
    order by ID desc --get the next one    

     set @RowNum = @RowNum - 1                              
     END 


household table
    1 bekshire st   dell    MA  10001   02639   50  0002    dell    NULL    ALRGEN  1   BERKSHIRE ST    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

individuals that belong to household id 10001
first    last     code
BOB BUILDER     U
JESS     BUILDER  A

i want 

1 bekshire st   dell    MA  10001   02639   50  0002    dell    NULL    ALRGEN  1   BERKSHIRE ST    BOB,JESS    BUILDER U,A
```

Comment: **What's the QUESTION?**

Comment: well the query has been going for 25 minutes and theres only about 7000 rows in total

Comment: there hasnt been an error yet but i would appreciate if someone would look at the code and let me know if i went about it the right way

Comment: You have multiple loops, what do you expect?

Comment: not sure this is the first multiple loop i have written whats a typical time frame for 7000 rows

Comment: Loops are slow in general since SQL is optimized for set operations.  You are going row-by-row at multiple levels.

Comment: my issue is even though i am looping and it takes time how come i dont see any records updateing wouldnt in my table

Comment: @JNK: that's row-by- **AGONIZING** -row (RBAR) :-)

Comment: Why can't you just create a single SQL that JOINs those three tables together and gives you back a single result set with all the names you want?? Would be **MUCH FASTER** and much more efficient than doing intertwined loops......

Comment: It would be better to give us your DDL and the expected output so that we could assist you in writing a query using JOINS that would actually do the work you are expecting.

Comment: You said up front that you're not worried about speed, is 25 minutes a problem now?  Maybe you should reconsider your statement and think about doing it right...

Comment: There is virtually no circumstance where using loops to do updates is the right choice.

Comment: i posted what i am trying to do up top, sorry if im completly off i just thought this was the best way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having to concatenate data to get it into the table, then your design is wrong. Please read up on normalization. A concatenated list should not be stored in a field. Each field in each row of data should have no more than 1 piece of information. What you need are related tables.

Comment: my issue is i am trying to pull household data into my program, but i want to pull individual data as well, my main goal was to get all the firstnames in one field and then the party codes in another without having multiple rows show up when i pull the data

Comment: i thought by creating a stored procedure and trigger to update the household data with these fields was the way to go but could u expand on how i would use related tables?